# Communicate using chat widget through facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to make a chat widget which includes functionality that you can chat with messenger and in that instead of redirecting user to messenger window i want to post messages to messenger on behalf of user and webhook of messenger will take care of rest.

The graph api only explains about how to send message on behalf of bot. Is it possible to send message on behalf of user using graph API+ messenger platform or something else?

Comment: No, that is not possible via API.

Comment: Is there any way to do that?

Comment: No, there is not.